# Facebook PHP-sdk username

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Simple question:

I've used php-sdk to get a hold of a users picture when logging in. Like this:

```
 $user = $facebook->getUser();

if ( $user ) 
{
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me'); .....

<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture"> ....
```

But I also want to get a hold of the username. I though I could do something like this, just add:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/username">
```

Of course this didn't work. I've tried many other "names" for a users name but I can't seem to find it! Someone got a simple solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are getting the username which you will not using like that, you should not be putting within an img tag..

Use the graph explorer for any kind of information on what are the possible results.

For the username get the response of 'me' and find the value of 'username'. See below for all kind of exploring on the Graph API..

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me

Comment: Okay :) thank you, I just though since you could do it within img source in javascript:

    image.src = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';

I could also do it in the php-sdk. But thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work without an access token:

`http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}?fields=username`